# React-Native navigation.addListener is not a functio

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation

Is there a way I can fix this without using redux?

This is only happening on iOS, on android the AddListener works perfectly fine without it.

[image: navigation.addListener is not a function]

I have a component and I call the props.navigation.addListener on the componentDidMount functon. 
Some code to help understand exactly where it breaks:

```
componentDidMount(){
    var _this = this;
    this.willBlurListener = this.props.navigation.addListener('willBlur', () => {
        _this.timer.clearTimeout();
    });
    this.willFocusListener = this.props.navigation.addListener('willFocus', () => {
        _this._action();
    });
    AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
}
```

And then I use the component like this:

```
<Inactivity name='SomeNameView' navigation={ this.props.navigation }>
    {this.renderDetails()}              
</Inactivity>
```

Comment: Can you please, share some code where the issue is coming.

Comment: Just edited the with some code snippets

Answer (score 2):

Can you please try to use `withNavigation` function, it returns a HOC that has navigation in it props so you don't have to pass from the parent component to the child:

I created a simple app that uses this concept that probably can help you:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  Button,
} from 'react-native';
import {
  createStackNavigator,
  withNavigation,
} from 'react-navigation';


class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.willBlurListener = this.props.navigation.addListener('willBlur', () => {
      this.someAction();
    })
  }

  someAction() {
    console.log('Some action is called!');
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.willBlurListener.remove();
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <View>
          <Text>Some Component</Text>
          <Button
              title={'Open settings'}
              onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Settings')}
          />
        </View>
    )
  }
}

const SomeComponentWithNavigation = withNavigation(SomeComponent);

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Home'
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
          <SomeComponentWithNavigation/>
          <Text>Welcome to home screen!</Text>
        </View>
    )
  }
}

class SettingsScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Settings'
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
          <Text>Welcome to settings screen!</Text>
        </View>
    )
  }
}

export default createStackNavigator(
    {
      Home: HomeScreen,
      Settings: SettingsScreen,
    },
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, appreciate your help Though this is a good tip, it does not fix my issue...

Comment: Can you please share the full code so that we can have a bigger idea!

Answer (score 1):

I have used `import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';` to achieve this. This could work for you as well.

Sample code example

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

class CurrentOrderClass extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
   this.onFocusSubscribe = this.props.navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
     // Your code
   });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
   this.onFocusSubscribe();
  }
  .
  .
  .
  .
  function CurrentOrder(props) {
   const navigation = useNavigation(props)
   return <CurrentOrderClass {...props} navigation={navigation} />
  }
}
export default CurrentOrder;
```

You can also check to React Native docs https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/

Answer (score 0):

I found this a bit tricky and after looking into it for a bit, I come up with the following solution. Note that is tested on `React Navigation 5.x`.

```
import { useIsDrawerOpen } from "@react-navigation/drawer";

let lastDrawerStateIsOpened = false;
const DrawerComponent = (props) => {
  const isOpened = useIsDrawerOpen();
  if (lastDrawerStateIsOpened != isOpened) {
    lastDrawerStateIsOpened = isOpened;
    if (isOpened) {
      // Do what needs to be done when drawer is opened.
    }
  }
};
```

Also, note that I'm using a functional component.